# How does IDLE run a .py module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle, nameerror

Windows 7 and Python v2.7.3

With this module "test.py":

```
print 'name: ' , __name__
print 'file: ' , __file__
```

I can go to CMD and type: `python test.py`

The result would be:

```
name: __main__
file: test.py
```

But if I open the file with IDLE and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program I'll get a `NameError` telling me `__file__` is not defined.

What steps does IDLE go through to run a .py module, and how is it different from running modules directly from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug, which has apparently (I don't use IDLE) [now been fixed](http://bugs.python.org/issue8515) - the discussion of the bug at that link has some explanation of what IDLE actually does to run your code.

Comment: I just tried __file__ in 2.7.13 (and 3.6.2) when running a file and its value is the full path in both.